# LINQ .Include()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

[image: Tables]

I'm trying to write some LINQ to join these tables but it's giving me errors. Here's my code

```
public PartialViewResult Getjobs(int id)
{
    using (var db = new MTEntities())
    {
        var jobs = db.jobs.Include(j => j.jobslist)
            .Include(jl => jl.jobslist.model_jobslist
            .Where(aa=>aa.jobslist.JobsListID==jl.jobslist.model_jobslist.JobsListID))
            .Where(bki => bki.BookingID==id)
            .ToList();

        if (jobs != null)
        {
            return PartialView("_JobDetails", jobs);
        }
```

I'm trying to display the approx time from the model_joblist table for the incoming booking id.

```
<th>
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model =>model.jobslist.model_jobslist.ApproxTime))
</th>
```

Is this possible?

> Error  5   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'JobsListID' and no extension method 'JobsListID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Controllers\BookingController.cs    90  97  MechanicTracker
>    thats the error

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple errors here. Firstly, I'd advise looking up include as include is not used for joins. You don't need it here at all to make the query work, but it will be useful for performance reasons.

Secondly, jobs being passed into `_JobDetails` will be of type `List<job>` so `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model =>model.jobslist.model_jobslist.ApproxTime))` is wrong.

Thirdly, if you want to display the value of ApproxTime you need `@Html.DisplayFor` not `@Html.DisplayNameFor`. However, as the snippet is in a th element maybe you did want DisplayNameFor and you haven't posted the relevent bit of code at all.

To create your query you can just use:

```
var jobs = db.jobs.Where(bki => bki.BookingID==id).ToList();
```

Add `Include`s later if you need them for performance. See links at end of answer for help on this.

Then for display it will depend on exactly what you want. You will have a list of jobs so it may be something like:

```
foreach (var job in Model) {
    ...Some HTML...
    job.jobslist.model_jobslist.ApproxTime.ToString("whatever date format you want")
    ...Some more HTML...
}
```

Some useful links:

[Date and time formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)

[How to use the include statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj574232.aspx)

[How to use the join statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669071(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: ok, so I can display the approx time from that one query ? do I not need to join tables?

Comment: @user2790781 no need to join. Entity framework will handle all the relationships as long as you have all the foreign keys set up correctly in your model.